# Google sign in HTML code is not visible when page is loaded

Tags: html, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have implemented the generated HTML (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator?hl=de) code to enable Google sign in for my web application (in django), but when i load the site the google button does not appear. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async ></script>

    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Login with Google</p>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="CLIENT-ID"
    data-context="signin"
    data-ux_mode="redirect"
    data-login_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/googleauth/"
    data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="rectangular"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is no error message so i am clueless how to fix the problem, especially as i am not a experienced developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I just want to make sure that you have created a [Google API client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id) and replace your client ID in `data-client_id="CLIENT-ID"`?

Since you are using `data-login_uri` and `redirect`, you also need to properly configure the Authorized redirect URIs (see [step 5](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id))

Thanks,
Herman